# How to show the json data in Pie chart HighChart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts, pie-chart

HI all i have a json data which looks like this

```
 [ "Data":[ 
 {"Id":"1  ","EmployeeName":Anil},
 ]
```

which i am geting from my controller action

```
       public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        var data = GetData();
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        int Param1;
        Param1 = 1;     
       var EmployeeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>().Select(e =>  
        new
         {
        id=e.EmployeId,
        Name = e.EmployeeName
       });
        return Json(EmployeeDetails , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

now i want this json data to a pie chart..how can i do this

Comment: How does your view look like? How have you tried to setup the pie chart? By the way your Index action does nothing with the result of the `GetData` method...

Comment: Are you using HighCharts or do you just want to create a pie chart? Asp.net has the ability to generate pie charts in MVC without needing a third party solution, and there are a ton of tutorial online on how to use it. Also as nemesv pointed out, `var data = GetData();` is not doing anything.

Comment: What information will be represented by each slice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here instead of calling your jsonresult method in action method do it using $.getJSON method

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    { 

    return View();
     }

  public JsonResult GetData()
   {
    int Param1;
    Param1 = 1;     
     var EmployeeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>().Select(e =>  
    new
     {
    id=e.EmployeId,
    Name = e.EmployeeName
   });
    return Json(EmployeeDetails , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

here u can call your method like this and bind it to your chart

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("YourMethod","YourControllerName") %>', {}, function (data) {
          var json = data;              
          var jsondata = [];              
          for (var i in json) {
             // var serie = new Array(json[i].Projects, json[i].Bugs);
              jsondata.push([json[i].EmployeId, json[i].EmployeeName]);
          }              
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              type: 'pie',
               plotBackgroundColor: null,
               plotBorderWidth: null,
               plotShadow: false
          },
           title: {
               text: 'Resource Reports of BugTracker'
           },

          plotOptions: {
              pie: {
                  showInLegend: true,
                  animation: false,
                  allowPointSelect: true,
                  cursor: 'pointer'
              }
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: true
          },
          series: [{
              type: 'pie',                 
              data: jsondata
          }]
      });
      });
  });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what type of data you have, creating a pie chart is fairly straightforward. See a working example here: http://livecoding.io/3437833

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      animation: false,
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
      ['Firefox',   45.0],
      ['IE',       26.8],
      ['Safari',    8.5],
      ['Opera',     6.2],
      ['Others',   0.7]
    ]
  }]
});
```